# Creating an App Community Page

Tags: facebook

I created an iOS App and i use a framework to share on Facebook. To do so, i created a Facebook App and i also created an App Community Page. Unfortunatly i had to change the name of the app so i deleted my App Community Page and now i can't create a new one.

The error message says (translated from French):

```
Name not valid
Creation of this content with this name is not authorized. Try with another name
```

How can i do to have an App Community Page without having to delete the application and making a new one ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your app is called must be on the Page name blacklist - rename the app and then you can create the page - it's usually caused by using a trademark or obscenity in the app name